# How to add elements to an object array property, if another property from the parent array is duplicated?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6

So, I have the following array:

```
const objectArray = [
    {
       'proyectId': 1,
       'fieldName': 'dog',
       'fieldValue': 'wof'
    },
    {
       'proyectId': 1,
       'fieldName': 'cat',
       'fieldValue': 'meow'
    }
];
```

How can I transform into this, for example using JS reduce or something like that:

```
[
    {
        proyectId: 1,
        customFields: [
            {'fieldName':'dog', 'fieldValue': 'wof'},
            {'fieldName':'cat', 'fieldValue': 'meow'}
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Please share your attempts.

Comment: Thanks Jeto! Greatly solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to index your objects by key (`proyectId`), then use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) to retrieve the values alone:

```js
const input = [{'proyectId': 1, 'fieldName': 'dog', 'fieldValue': 'wof'}, {'proyectId': 1, 'fieldName': 'cat', 'fieldValue': 'meow'}];

const result = Object.values(input.reduce((map, {proyectId, ...fields}) => {
  map[proyectId] = map[proyectId] || {proyectId, customFields: []};
  map[proyectId].customFields.push(fields);
  return map;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

PS: please share your attempts first next time, as suggested earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.reduce()` to convert the array to a Map by `proyectId`. Convert the Map to an array of entries (`[proyectId, customFields]`) with `Array.from()`, and use `Array.map()` to convert the entries to the objects format:

```js
const objectArray = [{"proyectId":1,"fieldName":"dog","fieldValue":"wof"},{"proyectId":1,"fieldName":"cat","fieldValue":"meow"}];

const result = Array.from(
  objectArray.reduce((r, { proyectId, ...o }) => 
    r.set(proyectId, [...r.get(proyectId)  || [], o])
  , new Map())
).map(([proyectId ,customFields]) => ({
  proyectId,
  customFields
}));

console.log(result);
```